# fetch data from google drive api

Tags: asp.net, api, google-drive-api

I want to access google drive api methods. i have access token for this. I am using c#.net. i basically want to create custom api methods for users so that they can pass access token to a method to invoke that. So i want to know if it is possible or not, and if possible then can i get an example for it.

I have searched a lot on google and found a 'Dr.Edit' sample aplication. It uses many methods for retrieving data but it uses driveservice object as a parameter in every method. this object consist of acccesstoken inside it but i did not find any way of getting data just by accesstoken.

Any help from your side would be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the C# example on how to [get authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials).